Tabulator Add rows to group by table below each group that was clicked
I have a requirement to add a button next to group header that inserts/adds new row after last row in the group.

I have this
groupBy:function(data){
        //data - the data object for the row being grouped

        return rowNum;
    },
         groupHeader: groupHeaderFormatter,

Defined groupHeaderFormatter as
function groupHeaderFormatter(value, count, data, group) {
    return value+ `&nbsp;&nbsp; ${count} items &nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="Tab_CREATE" type="button" value="New" onclick="groupHeaderButtonClicked()"/>`
}

However the addRow always insert at the end or beginning of the whole table. Please advice.
